# GWT Interface woes : Breaking on exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRestWrapper' of undefined

Tags: java, html, gwt, gradle, libgdx

I am writing a GWT app using Libgdx & having some difficulties loading the correct rest library at runtime.

In my core gradle project, I have defined a "RestWrapper" Interface that grants access to platform specific REST functions (in the case of GWT, RestyGWT). When the HTML5 launcher is run, it passes it's implementation to the LibGDX game class in the Core Project.

However when the HTML5 Project is run this error is raised by the compiled JS:

```
Breaking on exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRestWrapper' of undefined
```

The issue appears to be with the first interface (PlatformWrapper).
I understand the GWT compiler is a bit ham-fisted when it comes to interfaces, Should I be taking a different approach to running GWT specific code from my core project?

Calling code (In core Project:)

```
UserSessionToken token =client.getPlatform().getRestWrapper().getRestLogin().attemptLogin(userNameBox.getText(),passwordBox.getText());
```

Interfaces (In core Project):

PlaformWrapper

```
public interface PlatformWrapper {

public RestWrapper getRestWrapper();....
```

RestWrapper

```
/* Platform independent wrapper for REST services */ 
public interface RestWrapper {

public RestLogin getRestLogin();....
```

Implementations (In HTML5 Project):

PlatformWrapper (Top level)

```
public class GWTWrapper implements PlatformWrapper {

public RestWrapper gwtRestWrapper;

public GWTWrapper(){
    gwtRestWrapper = new GWTRestWrapper();
}

@Override
public RestWrapper getRestWrapper() {
    return gwtRestWrapper;
}
```

GWTRestWrapper:

```
public class GWTRestWrapper implements RestWrapper {
public RestLogin restLogin;
public RestPortal restPortal;
public RestRegister restRegister;

public GWTRestWrapper(){
    restLogin = new GWTRestLogin(); //GWTRest Logic 
    restRegister = new GWTRestRegister();
    restPortal = new GWTRestPortal();       
}


@Override
public RestLogin getRestLogin() {
    return restLogin;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Solution found: https://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/3bdxh0/html_not_working_desktop_and_android_ok/

Needed to create the RestWrapper after setup using a LoadingListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working change:

```
public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener () {


        setLoadingListener(new LoadingListener(){

            @Override
            public void beforeSetup() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterSetup() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                wrapper = new GWTWrapper();
                client.setPlatform(wrapper);
            }

        });
            return client;
```